# Async I/O operations - proper way to avoid deleting object

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

Using async I/O operations from `boost::asio` I often need shared pointers (and `enable_shared_from_this` and `shared_from_this` in callbacks) to avoid deleting objects too early.
I think that it could be done by keeping `unique_ptr` or just object (ownership) in class (as a member)

For example:
Only `foo` method use `sender`.

1st (popular solution):

```
class C {
    public:
    void foo
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Sender> sender = std::make_shared<Sender>();
        sender->send(); 
        // class Sender use async_write
        // inheritance: enable_shared_from_this
        // callback in async operation created with argument shared_from_this
    }
};
```

Why nobody(?) use this solution:

```
class D {
public:
    void foo
    {
        sender.reset(new Sender);
        sender->send(); 
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Sender> sender;
};
```

I know that sender will not be deleted to early. I have no shared_ptrs. I think it's good to avoid them because if callback in Sender class also use async operations I need another shared pointers etc. I think that class D is more friendly to read. 
But I wonder if it's a good style... and I always see solution with shared_ptrs in the net.

Comment: You have used make shared in a wrong way.

Comment: In this case, why do you think it is good to avoid `shared_ptr`?

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one `unique_ptr` to an object. What happens if you have both a send and a receive operation pending? What happens if you have both a receive operation and a timer?

Yes, you could use a `unique_ptr`, but then you'd have to implement your own count of the number of outstanding operations. You'd have to increment and decrement that count in a thread-safe way. And you'd have to constantly check if that count was zero to invoke the destructor. To clean this up, you'd likely bundle all this functionality into its own class. And you'd have reinvented `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

The latter usage is fragile and makes no guarantee that the sender will not be deleted too early.  For instance, consider the case where `D::foo()` is called consecutively, before the asynchronous operations have completed.  The previous `Sender` object could be deleted with outstanding operations that may depend on the `Sender` object:

```cpp
public: Sender
{
public:
  void send()
  {
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(buffer_), ...);
  }
private:
  std::array<char, 64> buffer_;
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;
  ...
};

D d;
d.foo(); // Create Sender1, initiate async_write.
d.foo(); // Delete Sender1, create Sender2, initiate async_write.
io_service.run(); // Sender1's async_write invokes undefined behavior.
```

In the above code, the second call to `d.foo()` will delete the first `Sender` object that has outstanding operations, resulting in undefined behavior.  On the other hand, if `Sender` inherits from `enable_shared_from_this`, and the result of `shared_from_this()` is bound to the handlers for asynchronous operations, then the `Sender` object's lifetime would extend to be at least as long as the operations.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at asio::spawn? Basically, it takes most of the complexity out of async C++ programming, and allow you to just put your objects on the stack.

Here is a simple example: [modern.cpp](https://github.com/jgaa/modern_async_cpp_example/blob/master/modern.cpp)

Using this approach saves a lot of time implementing and debugging an async application, and it makes the code really easy to understand. (I once implemented a RTP over TCP proxy, using traditional callbacks. It turned out to be a nightmare to maintain later on).

Regarding shard versus unique pointers - my experience is that shared pointers are simpler to use with asio. There were some problems moving unique pointers around, and when the program becomes slightly complex, it's really easy to make mistake mistakes. I think I would stick with shared and weak pointers as default - and only switch to unique pointers for objects where the profiler outputs suggests that it's worth the while.